# What are the minimum browser requirements for a base level MVC5 website project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser, compatibility, asp.net-mvc-5

I intend to develop a new MVC5 website in Visual Studio, and before I start I would like to know the minimum browser requirements of such a project before I even think about customising anything.

I've been googling for half an hour now and can't find an answer. I even tried Bing since it is Microsoft's search website.

What I'm trying to find out are the browser requirements that are imposed upon a website being a basic MVC5 project in Visual Studio.

I would like to support IE8 if possible, but mainly I just want to know one way or the other.

EDIT: What I mean is that the MVC5 project is bound to impose a certain minimum requirement on the web browsers being used to view it e.g. the version of bootstrap, jquery, etc. I can't find this information anywhere, and this is what I need to find out.

Comment: MVC5 is server, the browser compatibility will depend on what you do with your front-end. - javascript/css/html.

Comment: @mtbnunu I'm talking about an MVC5 project. I want to know what the minimum requirements are for a base level MVC5 project, before I even start to think about customising anything.

Comment: It usually comes bundled with bootstrap, but really it's up to you to build the master page with whatever library... I see this question as same level as browser compatibility for nodejs or PHP

Comment: While developing MVC5 application, you will use some JS. At that time you can think about compatibility of browser according to your JS used.